# How to find the nearest date to the current date

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on a problem where I want to display nearest date/time from the current date in Scala.

I have a data like below:

```
FlightTo    Date
-FT1      17-06-2019 
-FT2      19-06-2019
-FT3      23-06-2019 
-FT4      25-06-2019 
-FT5      27-06-2019
```

I want to find out the nearest date of flight which I can catch when check the data.
How to achieve this using Scala and Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window


val win =Window.orderBy("date_differnece")

val df= Seq(("FT1" ,"17-06-2019"), ("FT2" ,"19-06-2019"), ("FT3" ,"23-06-2019"),( "FT4", "25-06-2019"),("FT5", "27-06-2019")).toDF("flight", "dt")

val df1= df.withColumn("date_differnece", abs(datediff(current_date,to_date($"dt", "dd-MM-yyyy"))))

df1.select($"*", min($"date_differnece").over(win).as("nearest_flight")).where($"nearest_flight"===$"date_differnece").select($"dt")


+----------+
|        dt|
+----------+
|17-06-2019|
+----------+
```